# Completing values from a sparse representation of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a financial system application, in Microsoft SQL Server, that
requires calculating a `rate` for a given `tenor` (maturity in days) from yield
curves stored in a database. The problem is that the yield curves are stored
sparsely around `dates` and `tenors`; i.e. not all dates, and not all tenors,
are available in the database.

The yield curves are stored as this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Curves (
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    currency CHAR(3) NOT NULL,    
    tenor INT NOT NULL,
    rate DOUBLE NOT NULL
);
```

I want to be able to get a rate for a given `date`, `type`, `currency`, and
`tenor`. With the following assumptions:

- For a `givenDate`, choose the most recent curve for the given `type` and
  `currency`. If the `givenDate` is not found use the previously available date
  to get the rates.
- For a `givenTenor`, do a linear interpolation from the available `tenors`. If
  the `givenTenor` is smaller than the smallest tenor, use the rate associated
  with the smallest tenor. If the `givenTenor` is larger than the largest tenor,
  use the date associated with the largest tenor. For aything in between use a
  linear interpolation between the two closest tenors.

So assuming that I have another table with financial instruments:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Instruments (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    currency CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    tenor INT NOT NULL,
);
```

I would like to have a stored function that can produce the rates, following the
assumptions above, in a query like this:

```sql
SELECT *, SOME_FUNCTION(date, type, currency, tenor) AS rate FROM Instruments;
```

I believe that a function can be created to do this, but I'm also sure that a
naive implementation would not perform at all. Particularly with millions of
records. The algorithm for the function would be something like this:

- With the `givenDate`, get the `availableDate` as the maximum date that is less
  than or equal to the `givenDate`, for the `givenType` and `givenCurrency`.
- For the `availableDate` get all the `tenors` and `rates`. With this vector, go
  over the tenors with the asumptions as above, to calculate a rate.

Any ideas on how to do this in Microsoft SQL Server in a performant way?

-- Edit

Following up on @dalek @trenton-ftw comments, here is the 'naive'
implementation of the algorithm.  I've created random data to test:

- 5,000 Curve points, spanding the last 5 years, with two types and
  two currencies,
- 1,000,000 Instruments with random dates, types, currencies and
  tenors.

To test the function I just executed the following query:

```sql
SELECT AVG(dbo.TenorRate("date", "type", "currency", "tenor")) 
FROM Instruments
```

For the random sample above this query executes in 2:30 minutes in my
laptop. Nevertheless, the real application would need to work on
something close to 100,000,000 instruments in a heavily loaded sql
server. That would potentially put it in the 20 minute ballpark.

How can I improve the performance of this function?

Here is the naive implementation:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION TenorRate(
    @date DATE, 
    @type VARCHAR(8), 
    @currency VARCHAR(3), 
    @tenor INT
) RETURNS REAL
BEGIN

    DECLARE @rate REAL

    -- The available date is the first date that is less than or equal to 
    -- the provided one, or the first one if none are less than or equal to it.

    DECLARE @availableDate DATE
    SET @availableDate = (
        SELECT MAX("date") FROM Curves 
        WHERE "date" <= @date AND "type" = @type AND "currency" = @currency
    )
    IF (@availableDate IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @availableDate = (
                SELECT MIN("date") FROM Curves 
                WHERE "type" = @type AND "currency" = @currency
            )
        END

    -- Get the tenors and rates for the available date, type and currency.
    -- Ordering by tenor to ensure that the fetch is made in order.

    DECLARE @PreviousTenor INTEGER, @PreviousRate REAL
    DECLARE @CurrentTenor INTEGER, @CurrentRate REAL

    DECLARE Curve CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
        SELECT "tenor", "rate" 
        FROM Curves 
        WHERE "date" = @availableDate AND "type" = @type AND "currency" = @currency 
        ORDER BY "tenor"

    -- Open a cursor to iterate over the tenors and rates in order.

    OPEN Curve
    FETCH NEXT FROM Curve INTO @CurrentTenor, @CurrentRate 

    IF (@Tenor < @CurrentTenor) 
    BEGIN
        -- If the tenor is less than the first one, 
        -- then use the first tenor rate.
        SET @rate = @CurrentRate
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN        
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                IF (@Tenor = @CurrentTenor)
                BEGIN
                    -- If it mathces exactly return the found rate.
                    SET @rate = @CurrentRate
                    BREAK
                END
                IF (@Tenor < @CurrentTenor)
                BEGIN
                    -- If the current tenor is lesss than the current 
                    -- (but not equal) then interpolate with the 
                    -- previous one and return the calculated rate.
                    SET @rate = @PreviousRate + 
                        (@tenor - @PreviousTenor) * 
                        (@CurrentRate - @PreviousRate) / 
                        (@CurrentTenor - @PreviousTenor)
                    BREAK
                END
                -- Keep track ot the previous tenor and rate.
                SET @PreviousTenor = @CurrentTenor
                SET @PreviousRate = @CurrentRate
                -- Fetch the next tenor and rate.
                FETCH NEXT FROM Curve INTO @CurrentTenor, @CurrentRate
            END
        IF (@Tenor > @CurrentTenor) 
        BEGIN
            -- If we exahusted the tenors and still nothing found, 
            -- then use the last tenor rate.
            SET @rate = @CurrentRate
        END
    END

    CLOSE Curve
    DEALLOCATE Curve

    RETURN @rate

END;
```

Comment: If you are using SQLServer 2019 and if you can write the function as a 'scalar function' then you can take advantage of the new 'UDF inlining' capability as in:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a Table-Valued Function (TVF)  called via a CROSS APPLY.

Comment: Could you give a better definition on how you envision a `a linear interpolation between the two closest tenors` would be done using this data?

Comment: @trenton-ftw Assuming I have `(t1, r1)` and `(t2, r2)` but I'm looking for `t` (which is not `t1` or `t2`) with `t1 < t < t2`, then the linear interpolation of `r` would be `r1 + (t - t1)*((r2 - r1)/(t2 - t1))`.

Comment: Off-topic: In your first table you use `rate DOUBLE NOT NULL`, but DOUBLE isn't a data type in SQL Server. You can use FLOAT or REAL. Check SQL Server data types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#approximate-numerics

Comment: @RicardoMarimon alright that makes sense. Please give your attempt at creating this function yourself. SO is not a code writing service. Give your best attempt on this and then we can give input either on a better approach or correct your given approach.

Comment: @DaleK  I have updated the question to incorporate my naive implementation. I was expecting it to be low performance and indeed it is. I'm getting 1 million instruments processed on 2:30 minutes.

Comment: @trenton-ftw would very much appreciate your input.

Comment: @RicardoMarimon the answer to this question is highly dependent on the data you have in your system. You are essentially testing conditions until you find a condition that works for your input data, so a highly optimized solution is going to require consideration of the frequency of the given scenarios you are testing for in your system. In your cursor loop you have 4 scenarios you test for (using `IF`). Could you tell us what % of records within `Instruments` table evaluate to true for each `IF`? For example, how many records evaluate `IF (@Tenor < @CurrentTenor)` to true (and so forth)?

Comment: @RicardoMarimon a couple of general notes... 1. Cursors are rarely the answer to high performance. I'll admit the usage of a cursor here is not overly horrible given the variability of the scenarios you need to test for (and the rows required to do that), but it is certainly going to prevent this function from scaling. 2. You should add indexes to `Curves` table. 3. The `Instruments` table should have a defined clustered key. 4. Your use case may not be best supported by a function. There could be data warehousing solutions that best fit your need, or even just working with a stored procedure.

Comment: @trenton-ftw The majority of `@Tenors` (maybe some 80%) would be resolved within the first two or three `@CurrentTenors`, so the test would run very few times on average. Perhaps reading the whole vector of tenors and rates as a vector (don't know if it is possible) and then iterate over that would be more performant. In terms of being a function, it would allow many users to just add `dbo.TenorRate("date", "type", "currency", "tenor")` to their queries and get the functionality from a single source of truth.

Comment: @RicardoMarimon is adding indexes an option? The most scalable function is going to be a function that operates in a set based fashion (and not row based like cursors) and takes advantage of UDF inlining. This is going to perform much better with a supporting index. A non-clustered index on the table `Curves` on `type`,`currency`,`date` with `tenor` and `rate` included would be one option. Given that the table does not currently have a defined clustered index (which is bad IMO), you could instead create a non-unique clustered index on `type`,`currency`,`date`.

Comment: And knowing whether or not we can do that and which option you take affects how we can write the best performing function. The best option would be the non-unique clustered index IMO. Once you answer that question I will give you an answer. Sorry to ask so much.

Comment: @trenton-ftw We can add any possible index we need. I'm not sure about what the set based fashion looks like in this case.

Comment: @RicardoMarimon alright I have a working exmaple of this function that is set based and inline-able. I generated test data comparable the volume you gave examples of, and running on my system the run time is roughly 10% of the function that you created. I verified the output matches in all except two circumstances: 1. This function is non-deterministic. If two rows exist in `Curves` that matches the date,type,currency and with different rates then your function is non-deterministically picking the result. I wrote mine to be more deterministic by picking the 'lowest' rate.

Comment: 2. Your specifications regarding picking the tenor to use: `anything in between use a linear interpolation between the two closest tenors`. Your function simply picks the first row in `Curves` it encounters based on the tenor value to run this linear interpolation. I took this specification to mean that you want the closest available tenor to the input tenor. For example, if two rows exist in `Curves' (that match type,currency,date) with tenor of 1 and 14 and input tenor is 12, should rate from tenor 1 or 14 be selected? I take it as 14, but your function would evaluate it as 1.

Comment: @trenton-ftw Thanks for taking the time to go over this. There is a unique key on (date, type, currency, tenor) so your first comment would not be a problem, there would only be one rate. In terms of the **linear interpolation** in your example, if tenor is 12 between $(1, r_1)$ and $(14, r_14)$ then the resulting rate would be $r_1 + (12 - 1) * (r_14 - r_1) / (14-1)$ (thinking about this in terms of sets we would probably need a row that have pairs of [tenor, rates] so that we could calculate the formula. Would love to see your implementation for inlining.

Comment: @RicardoMarimon The presence of the unique constraint on those keys is good info and I will adjust the function for that assumption.

Comment: @RicardoMarimon Your explanation helps, but to further my question... Is it the closest without being over? Let's say the input tenor is 10, and in the `Curves` table there are 3 rows (that match type,currency,date) with tenor of 5,9,12. I utilized ABS(`inputTenor`-`currentTenor`) to determine the two closest points, so my function would select lines with tenor 9 and 12. Your function would have used rows 5 and 9 because 9 was the closest to 10 without being over and 5 was the previous row. I will go ahead and post my function and we can discuss.

Comment: @trenton-ftw In the 5,9,12, when looking for 10, we need to get the 9,12 pair because 9 <= 10 < 12. It **is not** the closest to 10 (which would be 9) it would be the pair that contains the 10 (9 and 12).

Comment: @RicardoMarimon ok that makes a bit more sense. So in the case that the input tenor was 10 again and we had rows in `Curves` table with tenors of 8,9,17 the two rows to be used for the linear interpolation would be the rows with a tenor of 9 and 17 because 9<=10<=17. My current implementation would use the rows with a tenor of 8 and 9 because 8 and 9 are the rows with the two tenors 'closest' to the input tenor of 10. I can correct if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a table `dbo.Curves` exists with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Curves(
    [date] [date] NOT NULL
    ,[type] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
    ,currency [char](3) NOT NULL
    ,tenor [int] NOT NULL
    ,rate [real] NOT NULL
    ,UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([date] ASC,[type] ASC,currency ASC,tenor ASC)
    ,INDEX YourClusteredIndexNameHere CLUSTERED ([type] ASC,currency ASC,[date] ASC)
);
```

Notable differences from OP's DDL script:

- column `rate` has the data type corrected from `double` to `real`. Assuming this is the correct data type because the provided function stores `rate` values in variables with a `real` data type. The data type `double` does not exist in SQL Server.
- I have added a clustered index on (`type`,`currency`,`date`). The table did not have a clustered index in OP's DDL script, but should certainly have one. Considering the only knowledge I have of how this table is used is this function, I will design one that works best for this function.
- OP indicated this table has a unique constraint on (`date`,`type`,`currency`,`tenor`), so I have included.

Just to note, if the unique constraint that already exists does not require the provided order, I would recommend removing that unique constraint and the clustered index I recommended and simply creating a single clustered primary key constraint on (`type`,`currency`,`date`,`tenor`).

### Differences between OP's function and set based approach

- The actual flow is very similar to OP's provided function. It is well commented, but the function does not read top to bottom. Start from the `FROM` of the inner most subquery and read 'outwards'.
- This function is inline-able. You can confirm this once this function is installed to a given database using [Microsoft's documentation on this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15#checking-whether-or-not-a-udf-can-be-inlined).
- I corrected the input type for the `@i_Type` variable to `varchar(10)` to match the `type` column of the `dbo.Curves` table.
- I created the two tables and populated them with what I believe was reasonable randomized data. I used the same scale of 200:1 from OP's test scenario of 1m records in `dbo.Instruments` and 5k records in `dbo.Curves`. I tested using 80k records in `dbo.Instruments` and 400 records in `dbo.Curves`. Using the exact same test script from OP of `SELECT AVG(dbo.TenorRate("date", "type", "currency", "tenor")) FROM Instruments;`

  - OP's `CURSOR` based approach had a CPU/Elapsed ms of 57774/58654.
  - Set based approach I wrote had a CPU/Elapsed ms of 7437/7440. So roughly 12.6% elapsed time of the original.
- The set based approach is guaranteed to result in more reads overall because it is repeatedly reading from `dbo.Curves` as opposed to the `CURSOR` option which pulls the rows from `dbo.Curves` one time and then reads from the `CURSOR`. It is worth it to note that comparing execution plans on both function approaches in the test case above will yield misleading results. Because the `CURSOR` based option cannot be inlined, the logical operators and query statistics are not going to be shown in the execution plan, but the query plan for the set based approach can be inlined and so the logcial operators and query statistics will be included in the execution plan. Just thought I would point that out.
- I did validate the results of this compared to the original function. I noticed that there some potential areas for discrepany.

  - Both this function and the OP's `CURSOR` based option are doing math using `real` data types. I saw a few examples where it looked like the math, although using the same numbers between the `CURSOR` approach and the set based approach resulted in different numbers. When I validated that the output number, when rounded to the 5th decimal, matched exactly. You might need to track that down, but considering that you said you are building a financial application and a financial application is the classic example where `real` and `float` data types should be avoided (because they are approximate data types) I **strongly** suggest you change the way these values are both stored and used in this function to be numeric. It was not worth my time to track this issue down because IMO it only exists because of very bad practice that should be resolved anyhow.
  - Based on my understanding of OP's approach, in scenarios where the input tenor is between the minimum and maximum tenor we would want to use the two rows from `dbo.Curves` where the tenor value is as close to the input tenor as possible, and then use those two rows (and the `rate` from those two rows) to perform a linear interpolation for the input tenor. In this same scenario, the OP's function finds the closest tenor available and then instead of using the row with the next closest available tenor, it uses the tenor with the previous row (sorted by `tenor ASC`). Because of how the `CURSOR` implementation was written, this is not guaranteed to be the next closest row to the input tenor so I fixed that in my approach. Feel free to revert if I misunderstood.

### Notes about my specific implementation

- This approach is not heavily optimized towards certain conditions that might exist more commonly. There are still potential optimizations that you might be able to make in your system based on the conditions that exist.
- I am using an aggregate to pivot rows to columns. I did test out `LEAD`/`LAG` to do this, but found that pivoting using the aggregate was consistently faster by roughly 7% decrease in elapsed time.
- There are simple warehousing strategies that could be used to **GREATLY** increase the performance of this approach. For example, storing the pre-calculated min/max for a given combination of a (`type`,`currency`,`date`) could have a tremendous impact.

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.TenorRate(
    @i_Date DATE
    ,@i_Type VARCHAR(10)
    ,@i_Currency CHAR(3)
    ,@i_Tenor INT
) 
RETURNS REAL
BEGIN
RETURN (
SELECT 
    /*now pick the return value based on the scenario that was returned, as a given scenario can have a specific formula*/
    CASE 
        WHEN pivoted_vals.Scenario = 1 THEN pivoted_vals.CurrentRate /*returned row is first row with matching tenor*/
        WHEN pivoted_vals.Scenario = 2 THEN pivoted_vals.CurrentRate /*returned row is row with smallest tenor*/
        WHEN pivoted_vals.Scenario = 3 THEN pivoted_vals.CurrentRate /*returned row is row with largest tenor*/
        WHEN pivoted_vals.Scenario = 4 /*returned row contains pivoted values for the two rows that are two closest tenor rows*/
            THEN pivoted_vals.PreviousRate
                 + 
                 (@i_Tenor - pivoted_vals.PreviousTenor) 
                 * 
                 (pivoted_vals.CurrentRate - pivoted_vals.PreviousRate) 
                 / 
                 (pivoted_vals.CurrentTenor - pivoted_vals.PreviousTenor)
    END AS ReturnValue 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        /*pivot rows using aggregates. aggregates are only considering one row and value at a time, so they are not truly aggregating anything. simply pivoting values.*/
        MAX(CASE WHEN top_2_rows.RowNumber = 1 THEN top_2_rows.Scenario ELSE NULL END) AS Scenario
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN top_2_rows.RowNumber = 1 THEN top_2_rows.CurrentRate ELSE NULL END) AS CurrentRate
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN top_2_rows.RowNumber = 1 THEN top_2_rows.CurrentTenor ELSE NULL END) AS CurrentTenor
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN top_2_rows.RowNumber = 2 THEN top_2_rows.CurrentRate ELSE NULL END) AS PreviousRate
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN top_2_rows.RowNumber = 2 THEN top_2_rows.CurrentTenor ELSE NULL END) AS PreviousTenor
    FROM 
        /*return a row number for our top two returned rows. done in an outer subquery so that the row_number function is not used until the final two rows have been selected*/
        (SELECT TOP (2)  
            picked_curve.Scenario
            ,picked_curve.ScenarioRankValue
            ,picked_curve.CurrentRate
            ,picked_curve.CurrentTenor 
            /*generate row number to match order by clause*/
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY picked_curve.Scenario ASC,picked_curve.ScenarioRankValue ASC) AS RowNumber 
        FROM 
            /*we need top two rows because scenario 4 requires the previous row's value*/
            (SELECT TOP (2) 
                scenarios.Scenario
                ,scenarios.ScenarioRankValue
                ,c.rate AS CurrentRate
                ,c.tenor AS CurrentTenor 
            FROM 
                /*first subquery to select the date that we will use from two separate conditions*/
                (SELECT TOP (1) 
                    date_options.[date]
                FROM 
                    (/*most recent available date before or equal to input date*/
                    SELECT TOP (1) 
                        c.[date]
                    FROM 
                        dbo.Curves AS c
                    WHERE 
                        /*match on type and currency*/
                        c.[type] = @i_Type 
                        AND 
                        c.currency = @i_Currency
                        AND 
                        c.[date] <= @i_Date
                    ORDER BY 
                        c.[date] DESC
                    UNION ALL 
                    /*first available date after input date*/
                    SELECT TOP (1) 
                        c.[date]
                    FROM 
                        dbo.Curves AS c
                    WHERE 
                        /*match on type and currency*/
                        c.[type] = @i_Type 
                        AND 
                        c.currency = @i_Currency
                        AND 
                        c.[date] > @i_Date
                    ORDER BY 
                        c.[date] ASC) AS date_options 
                ORDER BY 
                    /*we want to prioritize date from first query, which we know will be 'older' than date from second query. So ascending order*/
                    date_options.[date] ASC) AS selected_date 
                /*go get curve values for input type, input currency, and selected date*/
                INNER JOIN dbo.Curves AS c ON 
                    @i_Type = c.[type] 
                    AND 
                    @i_Currency = c.currency
                    AND 
                    selected_date.[date] = c.[date] 
                /*go get max and min curve values for input type, input currency, and selected date*/
                OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) /*TOP (1) is redundant since this is an aggregate with no grouping, but keeping for clarity*/
                                MAX(c_inner.tenor) AS MaxTenor
                                ,MIN(c_inner.tenor) AS MinTenor
                            FROM 
                                dbo.Curves AS c_inner 
                            WHERE 
                                c_inner.[type] = @i_Type
                                AND 
                                c_inner.currency = @i_Currency
                                AND 
                                c_inner.[date] = selected_date.[date]) AS max_min_tenor
                /*for readibility in select, outer apply logic to give us a value will prioritize certain scenarios over others (and indicate to us the scenarios that was returned) and 
                return the minimum number of rows that are ranked in a manner in which the top returned rows contain the information needed for the given scenario*/
                OUTER APPLY (SELECT
                                CASE /*rank the scenarios*/
                                    WHEN @i_Tenor = c.tenor THEN 1
                                    WHEN @i_Tenor < max_min_tenor.MinTenor THEN 2
                                    WHEN @i_Tenor > max_min_tenor.MaxTenor THEN 3
                                    ELSE 4 /*input tenor is between the max/min tenor*/
                                END AS Scenario
                                ,CASE /*rank value that ensures the top row will be the row we need for the returned scenario*/
                                    WHEN @i_Tenor = c.tenor THEN c.tenor 
                                    WHEN @i_Tenor < max_min_tenor.MinTenor THEN c.tenor 
                                    WHEN @i_Tenor > max_min_tenor.MaxTenor THEN c.tenor*-1
                                    ELSE ABS(c.tenor-@i_Tenor)
                                END AS ScenarioRankValue) AS scenarios
            ORDER BY 
                /*highest priority scenario (by lowest value) and the associated value to be ranked, which is designed to be used in ascending order*/
                scenarios.Scenario ASC
                ,scenarios.ScenarioRankValue ASC) AS picked_curve
        ORDER BY 
            picked_curve.Scenario ASC 
            ,picked_curve.ScenarioRankValue ASC) AS top_2_rows) AS pivoted_vals
); 
END; 
GO
```

Just one last note on usage, there are certain ways that you might use this query that could prevent it from being inline. I highly recommend you read the entirety of Microsoft's doc on [Scalar UDF Inlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining), but at a minimum you should at least read over the [Inlineable scalar UDF requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining#inlineable-scalar-udfs-requirements) contained in that same doc.

Hopefully this helps you out or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the time you've taken to go over this response. I would go over line by line to make sure that I can understand everything.

Answer (score 0):

In fact your function look like an aggregate function. If it is the case, you should write a SQL CLR one. We do that for financial score and the performance was fine...

Comment: You could better summarize the requirement (and thus the point of the function) as selecting the row (or sometimes two rows) from the table `Curves` that should be used to return the needed value. Very little about this function actually requires any aggregation and the returned value is very simply selected from the identified row. If the `CURSOR` based approach was required or could not be outperformed by an inlined set based approach (like I demonstrated) and the only purpose of this function was for an aggregate, then that might be the right approach. But none of that is the case here.

Comment: Could you write a CLR function to do this? Sure, just like any other SQL function can be written in CLR, but IMO you would not be able to write a CLR function that would significantly outperform an inlined set based approach to this, whether the output of the function is aggregated or not. The additional work and maintenance that comes with CLR integration is not worth it when a relatively simple function can fit the need.